# How to send webpages from Google Chrome to chrome Android phone?

Tags: android, angularjs, google-chrome

How to send webpages (application web AngularJs) started with http://**localhost**:9966/... from Google Chrome to your Android phone ?
For debbuging in phone ?

Answer (score 1):

*your system and your android shares same WiFi network*

The local address will run on your android because it's just the same network.

**OR**

If it's not on same network , you can install a third party app *ngrok*(Google it)  it will make your local link `http://localhost:9966/myapp..` access over the internet by providing a link `eg: http://djfb37047.ngrok.io/myapp` . Just input this link in your android browser and you are ready to go!

For debugging, check (this)[https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server ] out.